# Print recursive * pattern

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I have trouble printing the * pattern.

They should have 2 functions: printStars() and printLine(). printStars(int n), is used to print a line of n stars; the second one, printLines(int m), is to print m pairs of lines.

I have completed print half top but I could not reverse the pattern of the second half. You can't add more functions. There are only 2 functions printStars() and printLines() and must be recursive

The requirement:

```
* * * *
* * *
* *
* 
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

Here is what I have done:

```
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Code:

```
void printStars(int n){
    if (n < 1) return;
    cout << "*";
    printStars(n-1);
}

void printLines(int m){
    if (m < 1) return;
    printStars(m);
    cout << "\n";
    printLines(m-1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int n;
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    printLines(n);
}
```

Hint from the question: Think in the way that the whole picture is generated in the following pattern:

[image: Hint]

Comment: There is no reason to use recursion for such a case. Having loops is simpler.

Comment: Yeah. Loop is much easier but they asked to do it with recursive bro

Comment: What trouble are you having?  It would seem that your program is half complete.  Are you saying that you don't know how to write the second half?  Also, if "they asked" that you must write this a certain way, please include all those requirements in your question.

Comment: You may want to make a top half and bottom half function. Your current function is the top half

Comment: Think about what recursion does and use your conclusions to decide where you need to print more stars. If it helps, recursive functions like this are usually symmetrical.

Comment: Sorry guys. I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the small change you need:

```
void printLines(int m){
    if (m < 1) return;
    printStars(m);
    cout << "\n";
    printLines(m-1);

    printStars(m); // just add these two lines to print line again after all internal ones are printed
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't get it why when m < 1. It returns (end the program right?) how could it possible to loop it m from 1 -> m (m++) again?

Comment: @ThienNguyen no, return just exits from function, ie - returns to caller place

Comment: But I don't get it how could you increment the m again from (0->m) after you print upper half?

Comment: @ThienNguyen expression `m-1` does not change `m`